# Unusual Call to Kendo DataSource Read

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have question that I hope someone can answer. I was looking at the [Grid Hierarchy example here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/hierarchy) and in the example they are making two calls. `.Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Employees", "Grid"))` and `.Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Orders", "Grid", new { employeeID = "#=EmployeeID#" }))`. This seems counter-intuitive to me since they should be passing the model with the data to the view, and doing two calls seems costly. Can some one explain the reasoning for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without going into the technical details Let me explain in a simple words.

**Making two call is actually a good design idea** think about a scenario of **imaginary admin dashboard on amazon** that lists users and nested hierarchy order grid. So do you want to load all the user and there orders at one time in one call ?  or you think we should send a userid of a one person we are interested to nested hierarchy grid and getting only those record is better. *Hope it make sense.*

Comment: Yeah that make sense. I assume that the 2 calls where being made for all rows, but it was just for the first row.

Comment: one call to load the parent grid and then on demand single call to load the data when you expand a row for optimization.